# Decrypting NTFS encrypted files without booting old Windows installation

Tags: windows-7, encryption, ntfs

I have an old disk drive with Windows installed and it has a bunch of encrypted files I'd like to access again. However, I stopped using this installation a while ago because it's infected with viruses, so I'd really prefer not to boot it in order to export the certificate.

Is there any other way to get the encryption keys? The entire filesystem is intact.

**Edit:** Please don't suggest paid tools, I'm already aware of those and don't consider these files worth paying for.

**Edit 2:** Sorry, I guess I haven't made myself clear. I'm not talking about full volume encryption, only about file and folder encryption. It's the one where the file name goes green in Windows Explorer. The Windows installation is not encrypted, only some personal files.

Comment: "Is there any other way to get the encryption keys?"  - If they were contained on the encrypted volume, and if you don't already have them, then its to late to access them. "Please don't suggest paid tools" - Software recommendations, are not on topic, so we won't be suggesting free tools either.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. I've edited the post to try and clear it up. As for tools, I'd definitely prefer a practical answer where I learn something over a program; I was just trying to save the answering people's time.

Comment: "It's the one where the file name goes green in Windows Explorer. The Windows installation is not encrypted, only some personal files." - My answer is the same, while you are not using FDE, your encryption is tied to the user profile.  Which means your using EFS which stands for encrypted file system, and if the only place the keys are located are on the hdd within the profile that is encrypted, you can't access them.

Comment: I can access the HDD just fine, I'm just not willing to boot from it.

Comment: So your not using EFS or FDS.  So what did you use to encrypt individual folders because, "It's the one where the file name goes green in Windows Explorer. ", is EFS.  My answer is the same if you don't already have a backup of the keys, then you can't decrypt the files, end of story.

Comment: Right-click in Explorer > Properties > Attributes (Advanced...) > Encrypt contents to secure data. I can boot from the hdd, I'd just prefer not to for fear of rootkits.

Comment: Yeah; Your using EFS; Like I said if you don't already have the keys accessible without booting to the HDD, you can't decrypt your files, without booting to the HDD

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid this was the case. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an old disk drive with Windows installed and it has a bunch of
>   encrypted files I'd like to access again.
>
> .....
>
> I selected Right-click in Explorer > Properties > Attributes (Advanced...) >
>   Encrypt contents to secure data. I can boot from the hdd, I'd just
>   prefer not to for fear of rootkits.
>
> ...
>
> It's the one where the file name goes green in Windows Explorer. The
>   Windows installation is not encrypted, only some personal files.

The certificate to your files are connected to your user profile on the infected HDD.  This means that unless you create a backup of the certificate yourself, the only copy of that certificate that exists, is located on the infected HDD connected to the user profile that encrypted the files.

For security reasons this also means that that only way to access the certificate in order to back it up, is to boot to the HDD, and log into the user.